# Append argument to ENTRYPOINT in Docker run where some args are already defined

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm using `ENTRYPOINT` to pass in an argument when running `docker run` but I cannot get the runtime argument to surface in my script as an argument.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:latest

ENV a="my arg in Dockerfile"

COPY . .
RUN chmod +x myscript.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/myscript.sh ${a}"]
```

with **myscript.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "From script: $@"
```

When I run `docker build -t my_image .` then `docker run -it --rm my_image` I get the result as expected: `From script: my arg in Dockerfile`

But when I run `docker run -it --rm my_image from_run` I get the same result: `From script: my arg in Dockerfile` so the "from_run" is not being passed down to the script through `ENTRYPOINT`.

I read that arguments passed after the image name is appended to the `ENTRYPOINT` but clearly I'm not understanding something here.

Same result when using the exec form as opposed to JSON form:

```
ENTRYPOINT /myscript.sh ${a}
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime

Comment: Brilliant question (good answer too) - no idea why it was downvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main container command is made up of two parts.  The string you pass after the `docker run image-name` replaces the Dockerfile `CMD`, and it's appended to the Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT`.

For your `docker run` command to work, you need to provide the command you want to run as `ENTRYPOINT` and its arguments as `CMD`.  You do not need an environment variable here.  However, it is important that both parts use JSON-array syntax and that neither invokes a shell.  If `ENTRYPOINT` includes a shell then things get syntactically complex (see [@KamilCuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73877315)); if `CMD` includes a shell then it won't get invoked but the command will be invoked with `/bin/sh` and `-c` as parameters instead.

```bash
FROM debian:latest
COPY myscript.sh /usr/local/bin/myscript # preserves execute permissions
ENTRYPOINT ["myscript"]                  # in a $PATH directory
CMD ["my", "arg", "in", "Dockerfile"]
```

```bash
docker run --rm the-image
docker run --rm the-image my arg from command line
```

If you want the initial set of command-line arguments to be included and the `docker run` arguments to be appended, you can move them into the `ENTRYPOINT` line; note that the `docker run --entrypoint` is syntactically awkward if you ever do decide you need to remove some of the options.

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["myscript", "--first-default", "--second-default"]
# CMD []
```

```bash
docker run --rm the-image
docker run --rm the-image --user-option
docker run --entrypoint myscript the-image --first-default --no-second-default
```

If you can update your application to accept options as environment variables in addition to command-line settings, this makes all of this syntactically easier.

```bash
ENV FIRST_DEFAULT=yes
ENV SECOND_DEFAULT=yes
CMD ["myscript"]
```

```bash
docker run --rm the-image
docker run --rm -e USER_OPTION=yes the-image
docker run --rm -e SECOND_DEFAULT=no the-image
```

Comment: What a great explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Bash is Bash, see bash manual how `-c` pases arguments. The following:

```
/bin/bash -c "/myscript.sh ${a}" from_run
```

passes only one argument to myscript.sh and that is unquoted `$a`, so `$a` undergoes word splitting and filename expansion. And the argument `from_run` is assigned to `$0`. I would do:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "./myscript.sh \"$a\" \"$@\"", "--"]
```

Note that it's typical to use upper case (and unique names) for environment variables `$a`.